# Can I stop Google from listing my site when using keyword X but allow it for keyword Y?

Tags: seo, google-search

I have a website. When I search keyword X or Y on Google, I can see my website at the top of the result list.

Are there any ways not to show my website on the result list on Google when keyword Y was input while keeping my website at the top of the result list when keyword X was input?

Comment: All or nothing. Google scans and formulates its own opinions. Your control is to allow or deny access, or change content. You don't get the luxury of determining Google's search results.

Answer (score 4):

The possible solution of your problem would be removing *keyword Y* in good SEO places of your webpages like `<title>` or/and `<h1>` tag etc. (also think about looking at backlinks anchors).

You need to “de-SEO-optimize“ your webpages for keyword for which you don't want to see your site at the top of Google results.

Answer (score 1):

You can set a `<meta robots="noindex,follow">` on your page for the pages that contain keyword Y and keep `<meta robots="index,follow">` for the pages containing X. If both words are on the same page it's a not possible - or you would need to remove most of the keyword Y.

Answer (score -1):

i THINK IT ISN'T POSSIBLE . either you block the page from getting crawl where Y keyword is there . If you are running PPC than you can block for PPC

Comment: Welcome to Pro Webmasters! Your answer doesn't really make much sense to me. Can you update it to make it clearer? We generally prefer definitive answers instead of "I think the answer is XYZ".